# Show or hide HTLM according to the position of the user in the page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, show-hide

I want to create a horizontal navbar on my website.
I also want it to aprear and disapear "dynamically",
according to the position of the user in the page, but i can't manage to
do it properly. Here's my code :

HTML:

```
<script src='scripts/navbar.js'></script>
<ul id="navbar" onscroll="showHideNavbar();">
    <li>LOGOHERE</li>
    <li><a id="home-link-navbar">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="projects-link-navbar">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a id="about-link-navbar">About</a></li>
    <li><a id="contact-link-navbar">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    showHideNavbar();
</script>
```

and JS in navbar.js:

```
function showHideNavbar()
{
    console.log(window.pageXOffset);
    if(window.pageXOffset < 1000){
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.opacity = 0;
    }
    if(window.pageXOffset > 1000 && window.pageXOffset < 2000){
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.opacity = window.pageXOffset/10000*5;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.opacity = 1;
    }
}
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Post `navbar.js` too

Comment: The current js script is the one in the navbar.js . I'll corrrect my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call this function periodically, but you do it just once.

Do that with `setInterval()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(showHideNavbar,100);
</script>
```

Also, `pageXOffset` is the horizontal offset, but you seem to want `pageYOffset`.

Comment: ok, but where did i put it ? In the <script></script> selector in the HTML ?

Comment: It keep outputing me in the console "0", even when i scroll down.

Comment: CRAP ! I got it ! Sorry. I was looking for the X coord, but in fact i need to track the Y one ! It's ok now, i got good values.

Comment: @Noc Haha, indeed. Didn't even notice this. I'll add this to the answer just in case.

Comment: @Noc If you feel that I helped at least a tiny bit, you could accept the answer (click the checkmark). That's up to you to decide, I didn't fully address your problem initially.

Comment: Yes, u helped me btw ! I mark it as resolved. Thanks again !